# Clear all Sitecore Experience Profile data

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

I tried removing some Contacts from mongo db with Robomongo but Sitecore still lists my contacts in Experience Profile dashboard and now when I click on each I get a not found error now for the ones I deleted.

Is there a way to clear all the Experience profile data to have it like on a fresh installation?

Comment: Restore the analytics database in SQL server with a clean one.

Comment: As @jammykam said. If you have WFFM module you have to run script on the clean analytics database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow the instructions from the [Walkthrough: Rebuilding the reporting database article.](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/xdb_configuration/walkthrough_rebuilding_the_reporting_database) and delete all the files in sitecore_analytics_index folder

Comment: This is now a 404 link, it might now be this one? https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/walkthrough_rebuilding_the_reporting_database